# Why can I not deserialise a JSON string with single quotes in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using json to deserialize a string that is received from my MySQL database such that the resulting object is a dictionary.
This is the code:

```
sql.cursorobj.execute("SELECT * FROM timetableevents")
for record in sql.cursorobj.fetchall():
    print(record)
    obj= record['btnobject']
    detailsdict[obj]=json.loads(record['details'])    #I am facing an error here
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{'btnobject': 'btnobject1', 'details': "{'sno':[], 'time':[], 'events':[]}"}
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\veeru\Python 3.9.2\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "c:\Users\veeru\OneDrive\Visual Studio\Timetable\TimeTable.py", line 186, in <lambda>
  addtaskbtn.configure(command=lambda x=(btnobj, tableframe): ae.addtaskbtnclick(x[0], x[1]))
File "c:\Users\veeru\OneDrive\Visual Studio\Timetable\addevent.py", line 33, in addtaskbtnclick
  updateglobalvalues(btnobj)
File "c:\Users\veeru\OneDrive\Visual Studio\Timetable\addevent.py", line 22, in updateglobalvalues
  detailsdict[obj]=json.loads(f"{record['details']}")
File "C:\Users\veeru\Python 3.9.2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\veeru\Python 3.9.2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\veeru\Python 3.9.2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
  obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The last line in the above error code is of most importance ig.
I have tried enclosing the `record['details']` in double quotes explicitly
I have also used `fstrings` like: `json.loads(f"{record['details']}")`
**NOTE: **
Keep in mind that `json.loads(record['details'])` worked previously, but after I changed my database, it stopped working.

Comment: error msg is pretty clear you have single quote in your dict which makes it invalid as json, try using `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single quotes in our string and hence you get this error. What you can do is replace `'` with `"` and then do a `json.loads` as below:

```
sql.cursorobj.execute("SELECT * FROM timetableevents")
for record in sql.cursorobj.fetchall():
    print(record)
    obj= record['btnobject']
    # Replace ' with "
    details = record['details'].replace("'", '"')
    detailsdict[obj]=json.loads(details)    #I am facing an error here
```

Comment: It seems like this could fail for certain edge cases. What if `record['details']` already contains double quotes? What if there is just one single quote (eg: "this isn't that")?

Comment: If it already contains double quotes, nothing will be done. The code just replaces single quote with double quotes..

Comment: Right, but if you have a string like `"this can't be true"` you'll end up with `"this can"t be true"`, which is invalid json.

Comment: @BryanOakley is correct - this will break horribly wrong down the line with some form of data unless you're 500% sure of input and even then there are better ways

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON string is invalid.

From [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**, using backslash escapes.

It has single quotes while JSON strings should have double quotes to be valid.

You don't really have the option to mass replace the quotation marks from the database so use `json.dumps` before loading the JSON to convert the quotation marks.

Try this:

```
detailsdict[obj]=json.loads(json.dumps(record['details']))
```

Or use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
`detailsdict[obj]=json.loads(ast.literal_eval(record['details']))`
```

Answer (score 2):

if you try to load

```
print(json.loads('{"sno":[], "time":[], "events":[]}'))
```

it will give you no error cause key is in double qoute,
and you'll get the result

```
{'sno': [], 'time': [], 'events': []}
```

but if you cant change the output then try `json.dumps` first

```
print(json.dumps("{'sno':[], 'time':[], 'events':[]}"))
```

this will give you

```
'"{\'sno\':[], \'time\':[], \'events\':[]}"'
```